# Formulating a cell in Excel to auto populate

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I formulate a cell to remain blank when no data is entered; reflect N/A when a cell is less or equal to 4, and populate a response of Yes when a cell is greater than another cell?

I enter program year in one cell. cell `F6`. 
Cell `C33` automatically populates the response entered on `F6`. 
Cell `C32` populates automatically what should reflect base on `F6`. the formula on `C32` is

```
=IF(F6<=4,"DevelopmentalStage",IF(F6=5,"15%",IF(F6=6,"25%",IF(F6=7,"35%",IF(F6=8,"45%",IF(F6=9,"55%"))))))
```

Now I need for `C37` to remain blank when no data is entered, populate N/A when `C33<=4`, and populate Yes if `E35>=C32` and no if its less than. 
I have tried diferent variations. I just cant seem to have it populate all the required commands.

```
=IF(OR(C33="",E35=""),"",IF(C33<=4,"N/A",IF(E35>=C32,"YES","NO")
```

Based on the example of the picture since `E35` is larger than `C32` it should say yes.

[image: IMG:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're bumping into is that the logical comparison taking place between E35 and C32 is between incompatible formatting, therefore outputting the incorrect value.  You can test this by adding a logic check anywhere, e.g., `=E35>=C32`, which should output `TRUE` but — formatted as-is — it shows `FALSE` instead.

I've recreated the workbook and formatted / structured all the formulas correctly, which I've hosted [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Au6FcD8kvdA9gaZJXi-MopzM7brEHA?e=rqSxFW).  Screenshot: [image]